# Is it possible to show the player's cursor and/or see what keys they press when watching a replay?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm pretty sure that while watching some starcraft 2 replay commentaries I have seen the player who's perspective the game is being viewed from's cursor visible on the screen.

When I watch a replay I only see when the user clicks on something.

Is this a setting that can be changed, or did I just misunderstand what I was seeing?

---

The other thing is it would be really useful to be able to see what keys/key combinations a player uses. Sometimes you see a player doing something very quickly and efficiently, and it's difficult to work out exactly how they did it (for a beginner like me at least). Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only see a sort of echo appear on the screen I am afraid.

What you might have seen was the caster's mouse cursor when they review the replay, or some casters record a game they are playing live, so you see their mouse.

As for the key presses, I am afraid you have to be vigilant and work out what they click. Personally I have the shortcuts showing on the icons, which might help, A lot of the time it is just noise, keep an eye on the production, that will give you an idea of what they are clicking.

Make sure you watch Day9, he is Brrrrriliant and have good tips and tricks for a beginner and part-timer (such as myself).

I think you might be worrying to much about the detail and need to take a step back to see the larger picture.

This video might be a good start:

otherwise go back as far as you can and let Day9 guide you.

Comment: Thanks for the info! The thing in particular that I was trying to work out was building multiple buildings with multiple SCVs. It turns you you just select as many units as you need and then start building the structures, the units then split themselves up accordingly :)

Comment: ah yes, they are that. A fun one is when you are transferring some scvs to the gas, or visa-versa. If they are holding any minerals press C, and they will go to the Command Centre to drop off their minerals before continuing on to the gas.

Comment: Wow, that's a brilliant shortcut!